# Return the largest valid subset wherein the differences between values are within the range K

Tags: javascript, algorithm, data-structures

I am looking for **a solution with runtime better than O(n squared), or the most optimized solution** for this question.

I had this question come up in an interview.  I'll do my best to reproduce it:

Given an array of objects with properties 'year' and 'value', and a number k, return the largest valid subset of that array wherein the difference between max and min values of that subset is <= k.

**EDIT:** the objects in a valid subset do not have to be originally consecutive objects

For example:

```
data = [
  { 'year': 2002,
    'value': 1
  },
  { 'year': 2003,
    'value': 5
  },
  { 'year': 2004,
    'value': 4
  },
  { 'year': 2005,
    'value': 3
  },
  { 'year': 2006,
    'value': 3
  }
]

k = 1

solution: [
  { 'year': 2004,
    'value': 4
  },
  { 'year': 2005,
    'value': 3
  },
  { 'year': 2006,
    'value': 3
  }
]
```

In this example, another valid subset is:

```
  { 'year': 2003,
    'value': 5
  },
  { 'year': 2004,
    'value': 4
  }
```

But the other subset is longer, so you return that one.

One solution I came up with is to sort the two arrays, iterate over the sorted arrays, add all valid subsets to a new array, and then iterate over it and return the longest subset:

```
function findLargestValidSubset(k, data) {

  let allSubsets = []

  data = data.sort((a, b) => a.value - b.value)

  for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i].value - data[i-1].value <= k) {
      let subset = [data[i-1], data[i]]
      let j = i + 1
      while (j < data.length && 
        (data[j].value - data[j-1].value <= k) && 
        (data[j].value - data[i-1].value <= k)) {
        subset.push(data[j])
        j++
      }
      allSubsets.push(subset)
    }
  }

  let maxSubsetLength = 0
  let maxSubset
  for (var i = 0; i < allSubsets.length; i++) {
    if (allSubsets[i].length > maxSubsetLength) {
      maxSubset = allSubsets[i]
      maxSubsetLength = maxSubset.length
    }
  }
  return maxSubset
}

console.log(findLargestValidSubset(1, data))
```

This still seems like it is not the most optimized solution, and I am struggling to come up with one that is better.

Comment: Quoting Andreas: Asking the [exact same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68227127) a third time because the previous got closed doesn't make the new question any better. This is spamming and may be penalized.

Comment: @Reizo - I spoke to a moderator who had this to say: "There's no meaningful difference between the two questions. SO isn't a code-writing service, there's no evidence of any attempt at a solution, no evidence of researching or trying to implement ideas given in the previously-closed question, and so on. My suggestion would be to first spend some time with the problem itself, code up some potential solutions, and asking specific questions about specific implementations--that's more likely to get a positive response with constructive feedback :)"

Comment: So as you'll notice, I updated the question with my attempted solution, asking specifically for a more optimized solution.  I am doing my best to follow the guidelines that are being given to me.

Comment: You might find more appropriate help at https://codereview.stackexchange.com. Make sure to ask a specific question. If you post there, please comment here with a link. I'm interested in helping but I will have to look at it later tonight.

Comment: @Leaozinho alright, I've been a bit rash to state this question as exactly same. Sorry for that. Generally ideal procedure is to edit a question instead of posting a new, extended one. Then this confusion will not arise and answers can base on existing comments etc.

Comment: I did edit the original question, then I was also given this bit from a moderator: "@Leaozinho You may need to lobby on meta for the question to be re-opened or maybe start all over again, not sure what the best approach would be, sorry."  So I followed that advice.  I don't know if it's the best, but that is the information I'm being given.

Comment: do you want consecutive objects?

Comment: No, it can be any objects in the array that satisfy this requirement

Comment: Would love to see @NinaScholz's approach on this. She is very smart and writes beautiful, powerful programs.

Answer (score 1):

**wishful thinking**

We can approach this problem using one of my favourite programming techniques, wishful thinking. We simply write how we *wish* to express our program -

```js
console.log(longest(solve(remap(data), 1))) // k = 1
```

Then one by one, we make our wishes come true. You have good intuition to `sort` the input, however I'll go step further and group elements with the same `value` too. This allows us to skip potentially huge spans where the same `value` appears many times in a row -

```js
function remap (arr) {
  const m = arr
    .sort((a, b) => a.value - b.value)
    .reduce
      ( (m, t) =>
          m.has(t.value)
            ? m.get(t.value).push(t) && m
            : m.set(t.value, [t])
      , new Map
      )
  return Array.from(m.entries(), ([ value, items ]) => ({ value, items }))
}
```

Here's what our `remap`'d input looks like -

```js
remap(data)
```

```js
[ {value:1,items:[{year:2002,value:1}]}
, {value:3,items:[{year:2005,value:3},{year:2006,value:3}]} // <- grouped
, {value:4,items:[{year:2004,value:4}]}
, {value:5,items:[{year:2003,value:5}]}
]
```

Fulfill any remaining wishes. Next write `solver`. Stay as high-level as possible, without zooming too closely on any specific implementation detail. If the input array, `t`, has a length of less than two (2), there is nothing to solve. Otherwise for each array index of `t`, yield a single solution -

```js
function* solver (t, k) {
  if (t.length < 2)
    return yield [t]
  for (let i = 0; i < t.length; i++)
    yield solve1(solution(t, k, range(i)))
}
```

A `solution` is simply a collection of inputs, our input array, `arr`, our constant, `k`, and a selected `range` -

```js
function solution (arr, k, range) {
  return { arr, k, range }
}
```

Oh and a `range` is simply a `left` and a `right` numeric boundary -

```js
function range (left = 0, right = left + 1) {
  return { left, right }
}
```

To solve a single solution, we write `solve1`. If the input solution, `sln`, is `valid`, attempt to `grow` the solution and re-solve. Otherwise, the solution has outgrown `k` or the `arr` boundaries. `shrink` the solution and return its `subset` -

```js
function solve1 (sln) {
  if (valid(sln))
    return solve1(grow(sln))
  else
    return subset(shrink(sln))
}
```

Checking if a solution is `valid` is a matter of selecting the `left` and `right` boundaries. If the difference is less-than-or-equal to `k`, it is valid -

```js
function valid (sln) {
  const left = sln.arr[sln.range.left]
  const right = sln.arr[sln.range.right]
  return left && right && right.value - left.value <= sln.k
}
```

We can `grow` and `shrink` a single solution by incrementing or decrementing the solution's `range` -

```js
function grow (sln) {
  return solution(sln.arr, sln.k, range(sln.range.left, sln.range.right + 1))
}

function shrink (sln) {
  return solution(sln.arr, sln.k, range(sln.range.left, sln.range.right - 1))
}
```

To extract a solution's `subset`, we slice the solution's `arr` using the solution's `range`. Simply `flatMap` over the slice and select each element's `items` -

```js
function subset (sln) {
  return sln.arr.slice(sln.range.left, sln.range.right + 1).flatMap(v => v.items)
}
```

At this point our `solver` is functional -

```js
for (const subset of solver(remap(data), 1))
  console.lorg(subset)
```

```js
[{"year":2002,"value":1}]
[{"year":2005,"value":3},{"year":2006,"value":3},{"year":2004,"value":4}]
[{"year":2004,"value":4},{"year":2003,"value":5}]
[{"year":2003,"value":5}]
```

Finally we implement `longest` to compute the longest subset -

```js
function longest (it) {
  let r = []
  for (const v of it)
    if (v.length > r.length)
      r = v
  return r
}
```

```js
console.log("smalldata", longest(solver(remap(data), 1)))
```

```js
smalldata [{"year":2005,"value":3},{"year":2006,"value":3},{"year":2004,"value":4}]
```

**simple objects**

Note we are careful not to slice and manipulate the input as we solve. This is important because the input may be significantly large and each iteration would involve a costly operation on a large dataset. Instead we modelled `solution` and `range` as simple objects and perform step-by-step operations on these objects. We only extract a particular `solution`'s items once it has grown to the maximum size. On that note...

**one million elements**

Given an input of one million elements, we can calculate the longest subset of `k = 10` in less than one second -

```js
const randInt = (n) =>
  Math.ceil(Math.random() * n)

const bigdata =
  Array.from(Array(1e6), _ => ({ year: 1900 + randInt(120), value: randInt(1e7) }))

console.time("solver")
const answer = longest(solver(remap(bigdata), 10))
console.timeEnd("solver")
console.log("bigdata", JSON.stringify(answer))
```

```js
solver: 643.000 ms
bigdata [{"year":1901,"value":182530},{"year":1905,"value":182531},{"year":1988,"value":182533},{"year":1924,"value":182533},{"year":1930,"value":182535},{"year":1973,"value":182535},{"year":2010,"value":182536},{"year":1977,"value":182537},{"year":2011,"value":182540}]
```

**demo**

Expand the snippet below to verify the result in your own browser -

```js
function remap (arr) {
  const m = arr
    .sort((a, b) => a.value - b.value)
    .reduce
    ( (m, t) =>
        m.has(t.value)
          ? m.get(t.value).push(t) && m
          : m.set(t.value, [t])
    , new Map
    )
  return Array.from(m.entries(), ([ value, items ]) => ({ value, items }))
}

function* solver (t, k) {
  if (t.length < 2)
    return yield [t]
  for (let i = 0; i < t.length; i++)
    yield solve1(solution(t, k, range(i)))
}

function solve1 (sln) {
  if (valid(sln))
    return solve1(grow(sln))
  else
    return subset(shrink(sln))
}

function longest (it) {
  let r = []
  for (const v of it)
    if (v.length > r.length)
      r = v
  return r
}

function range (left = 0, right = left + 1) {
  return { left, right }
}

function solution (arr, k, range) {
  return { arr, k, range }
}

function valid (sln) {
  const left = sln.arr[sln.range.left]
  const right = sln.arr[sln.range.right]
  return left && right && right.value - left.value <= sln.k
}

function grow (sln) {
  return solution(sln.arr, sln.k, range(sln.range.left, sln.range.right + 1))
}

function shrink (sln) {
  return solution(sln.arr, sln.k, range(sln.range.left, sln.range.right - 1))
}

function subset (sln) {
  return sln.arr.slice(sln.range.left, sln.range.right + 1).flatMap(v => v.items)
}

const randInt = (n) =>
  Math.ceil(Math.random() * n)

const smalldata =
  [{year: 2002,value: 1},{year: 2003,value: 5},{year: 2004,value: 4},{year: 2005,value: 3},{year: 2006,value: 3}]

const bigdata =
  Array.from(Array(1e6), _ => ({ year: 1900 + randInt(120), value: randInt(1e7) }))

console.log("smalldata", longest(solver(remap(smalldata), 1)))

console.time("solver")
const answer = longest(solver(remap(bigdata), 10))
console.timeEnd("solver")
console.log("bigdata", JSON.stringify(answer))
```

```js
smalldata [{"year":2005,"value":3},{"year":2006,"value":3},{"year":2004,"value":4}]
```

```js
solver: 643.000 ms
bigdata [{"year":1901,"value":182530},{"year":1905,"value":182531},{"year":1988,"value":182533},{"year":1924,"value":182533},{"year":1930,"value":182535},{"year":1973,"value":182535},{"year":2010,"value":182536},{"year":1977,"value":182537},{"year":2011,"value":182540}]
```

**generators**

Generators are super powerful because they allow a function to return, or `yield`, *more than one* result. You may not have noticed it earlier in the post, but you can iterate over `solver` using a `for` loop to get all of its outputs, or use `Array.from` to collect them all in an array. However, to answer your specific question, `longest` consumes the entire generator and returns only a single value.

Comment: wow.  just going over this now but this is incredible.  thank you, Thank you.